# Extjs4, get radiofield value in Controller

Tags: extjs4

I have a radiofield in my Tbar.

```
var orderListTbar = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
    id : 'orderListTbar',
    items : [
        '',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            value : 'order_name',
            boxLabel : 'Order Name'
        },'',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            value : 'order_no',
            boxLabel : 'Order No'
        },'',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            value : 'status',
            boxLabel : 'Status'
        }
.
.
.
```

and I want to get the radiofield value in my controller.

**Q1. Is it available to add checked filter to query(), then how?**

```
var searchType = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#orderListTbar [name=searchType]");

console.log(searchType);
console.log(searchType.length); // return 3
```

I tried,

```
var searchType = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#orderListTbar [name=searchType]:checked");
```

but it doesn't work.

**Q2. How can I get the radiofield value?**

```
console.log(searchType[0].value); // return field name ,not value
console.log(searchType[0].initialConfig.value); // it return value
```

Is it right to put the "initialConfig", it looks weird.

Please advice me right direction how to use them correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the initialConfig property, you should try to stick with the API methods. It seems like your trying to see which of the radios is selected in your radiofield group.

You should use the `inputValue` config on each of the radios and then you can use the `getGroupValue` method to see which one is selected, for example:

```
var orderListTbar = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
    id : 'orderListTbar',
    items : ['',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            inputValue: 'Order Name is selected!',
            value : 'order_name',
            boxLabel : 'Order Name'
        },'',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            inputValue: 'Order No is selected!',
            value : 'order_no',
            boxLabel : 'Order No'
        },'',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            inputValue: 'Status is selected!',
            value : 'status',
            boxLabel : 'Status'
        }, {
            text: 'Which one is selected?',
            handler: function() {
                var searchType = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#orderListTbar [name=searchType]");
                console.log(searchType[0].getGroupValue());
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Depending on which radio is selected the "Which one is selected?" button will log "Order Name is selected!", "Order No is selected!" or "Status is selected!".

Comment: wow! it works perfectly! thank you. so I do not need to use 'value :' property in radiofield (also checkbox). right?

Comment: Not unless you want one of the radios to start out filled. `value:true`, `value:1`, `value:'true'`, or `value:'on'` will all make the radio start out as selected anything else will make it unselected. Most of this stuff is covered in the [intro for this element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio) in the API as @user1245590 suggested.